# Android: How to handle excpetions of activity which called by startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, exception, startactivityforresult

I'm calling an activity (e.g. `ExternalActivity`) inside my `MainActivity` by calling `startActivityForResult`.
There are some cases which exception occurs inside `ExternalActivity`. How can I handle and catch them inside my `MainActivity`?

Currently its exceptions are handled by an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` inside my application.

Comment: I would prefer, handling exceptions in ExternalActivity, and sending error code to MainActivity.

Comment: @BaluSangem This activity belong to an external .AAR library and I have no access to its source code for modification.